# Failing to subclass NSInputStream from Swift (initWithData: unrecognizer selector)

Tags: ios, swift, nsinputstream

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong to produce the following error:

```
2015-02-02 12:48:17.029 InputStreams[14816:221224] -[InputStreams.CustomStream initWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda2e1aac30
```

Here is my `CustomStream` subclass.

```
import Foundation

class CustomStream : NSInputStream {
    let streamName = "My Custom Stream"

    override init(data: NSData) {
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

And here's a quick example of how I'm trying to instantiate it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stream = CustomStream(data: NSData())
        println("Stream Name: \(stream.streamName)")
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So are we thinking this is a bug? Given the fact that this has sat open for this many days I think it's about time to file a radar.

Comment: I filed the following [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4504359098384384). Please dupe if you have the same problem. If you don't and figured it out, please help!

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Frankly, it also strikes me as a bug that I have to call one of their designated initializers (e.g. with `NSData` or `NSURL`) when the entire purpose of subclassing is that I probably don't want to use either of those. Frankly, subclassing `NSInputStream` has always been problematic (see http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html), but I was hoping they had looked at this over [the last 8 years](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2007/May/msg00056.html).

Comment: I'm running into this on an Objective-C project as well, so it's not Swift-specific.

Comment: FYI, I've tested it under Xcode 7 (beta 6). There's no issue.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the heads up @BPCorp.

Comment: I'm still getting the error with Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using `convinence` init.

```
class CustomStream : NSInputStream {
    let streamName = "My Custom Stream"
    // var data:NSData!        

    convenience override init(data: NSData) {
        self.init()
        // do inialization.
        // self.data = data 
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

To be honest I have not figured out why it works.I am referring to [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) for more information.Please leave a comment if you have any idea about it.

One more thing,it is considered safer to use `CFCreateBounderPair` rather than to subclass `NSInputStream`.I have tried to convert `ALAsset` to `NSInputStream` successfully in both ways successfully.The code is available here [ALAssetToNSInputStream](https://github.com/luowenxing/ALAssetToNSInputStream).